# Ts vector index on dynamic dictonary language

Tags: postgresql

I have big table that use a JOIN using ts_vector

```
SELECT
   queries.query

FROM reports
INNER JOIN queries ON (
    strip(to_tsvector('italian', reports.query)) = strip(to_tsvector('italian', queries.query))
OR  strip(to_tsvector('italian', reports.text))  = strip(to_tsvector('italian', queries.query))
)
```

Now this query it's really slow and I would like to follow what suggested [here](https://www.lateral.io/resources-blog/full-text-search-in-milliseconds-with-postgresql) and create a new ts_vector column (+index it) on the reports table that store the value of

```
strip(to_tsvector('italian', reports.query))
```

so I can search on this just created column. I am not interest to weights.

In the article is suggested to create a trigger function, but the problem is that the dictionary it could be 'italian', 'english', 'german' and so on..

The language could be calculated by a join with another table

```
SELECT
 language
FROM profiles
WHERE profileid = reports.profileid
```

But I suspect this could be complicated. How could I do?
Otherwise, I can run a scheduled script that manually populate the ts_vector column after importing/updating data to reports table. In this case I will switch language at the application-level.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  If the report is written in German, it is written in German.  If the person who wrote the report decides to change their profile, that doesn't cause the language of the report to change.  Why shouldn't language be directly in the report table?

Comment: Indeed, the language it's not present in the reports table. Only the index on to_tsvector needs to know what language it is.